# Does iOS "app transport security enforcement“ mean I need to switch APIs to https?

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I am now watching wwdc and saw this. Does it mean all api that I am using should already become htpps?

Also, in my info.plst, I put "Allow Arbitrary Loads" as YES. Do I need to remove and support https?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes. All your APIs should use https from the moment on Apple enforces this. <strike>(They announced this moment to be the January of 2017)</strike> Apple will enforce this in the future but they postponed the enforcement [to a date yet to be announced](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12212016b).

Your exisiting apps in the store will still work but you can not submit new apps that do not comply to ATS.

*Allow Arbitrary Loads* will definitely lead to a rejection then but you shouldn´t already use this today for your production app and rather use exceptions per domain.

Apple also announced that there will still be exceptions for servers that are not under your control. You can mark them as Third party exceptions with the help of the following entries in your plist file:

```
NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy
NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion
```

But there is no insurance that Apple will accept these servers as third party exceptions and therefore accept your app.

[Here](https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2016/08/14/ats-enforced-2017/) is some more information about the topic.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, I believe Apple has stated that they will allow Forward secrecy exceptions without the need for justification. So if you have a minimum TLS of 1.2 and a strong enough key, you can get by if your server's encryiption doesn't support forward secrecy.  It is still on a per-domain basis. but if you have a server that cannot and will not support forward secrecy, it will hopefully allow you to submit apps after 1/12017.

Comment: This is correct for now. I guess this will change in the future, too.

Comment: Probably, although there are companies who use security appliances that operate by inspecting traffic for certain types of attacks.  If all that data is encrypted without the ability to be decrypted, the appliance can't do its job.  This makes forward secrecy not an option for companies using those appliances.  But Apple has a way of making its own rules, so maybe they'll require it anyways at some point.